# pass object in cmd using argparse in nodejs

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, argparse

can anyone tell me is this possible to pass args as object
let me show my code sample

```
parser.addArgument(
                   ['-p', '--params'],
                   {
                    required: true,
                    help: 'folder name'
                   }
);
```

now my problem is that i want params as object like `params.echo=1 params.next=2` etc but it giving output like `params='echo=1'` when I'm providing syntax like

```
 node action-paths/test.js -f bipin -p params.echo="test"
 Namespace { folder: 'bipin', params: 'params.echo=test' }
```

Comment: Digging around in the `nodeca` repository for the `javascript` `argparse` (which I worked on years ago), I see that, `parseArgs` uses, as default the `process.argv` array.  Those are the strings it has to work with.  It doesn't get `objects`.  Your own code has to make the connection between those strings and any objects it has created or loaded from else where.

Comment: `argparse` is a standard library in `python`, but a 3rd party addon for `node`.  So don't expect the `[argparse]` tag to get as much attention.  But for your problem using `argparse` is a distraction.

Comment: @hpaulj can you suggest a way how i can achieve above requirement i mean is it possible to make child for params something like expected output  Namespace { folder: 'bipin', params:{echo:'test' }}

Comment: How about making a JSON string and decode that?

Comment: @hpaulj how? sorry for asking too much don't know how to do in this

Comment: I haven't used javascript since 2013 when I contributed to `nodeca`. Even then I preferred `coffeescript`.

Comment: @hpaulj just want example(weather wrong or right it not matter) i can make it i mean where i m getting json string if i type json in cmd it throw error

Comment: @hpaulj if i use subparser then why it note making something like this params:{echo:test}